# Google Drive API - Permissions error 403 when requesting file list using API key - C#

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, drive

I have been scouring the internet looking for a solution to this. I am using Google Drive API for my C# application. I have an API key for authentication. I opted out of using Oauth 2.0 credentials due to this project being for remote clients. It seems like the API key allows me to connect to the google project, but I am getting a permissions error when trying to execute a list request: (The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file. [403]).

All files/folders have been set to public, the API key is set with no restrictions, and Drive API is enabled. Any help would be appreciated.   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJemM.jpg also included an image link that shows the error output.

```
 private static void DriveTest(string clientVersionFile, string clientBuildFile) {

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
            ApiKey = apiKey,
            ApplicationName = appName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        // ---- ERROR 403 ON THIS EXECUTE CALL   ------
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

        // Loop through files and check for the requested file name. Once found, copy it's ID and break the loop.
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var file in files) {
                if(file.Name == clientVersionFile) {
                    downloadID = file.Id;
                    foundFile = true;

                    Console.WriteLine("Got the requested file");
                    break;
                  }
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: You have a two port application 1) Google Drive API  2) Connection to clients .  Do not get the two port mixed up.  The credentials to the clients are different from the connection to the API.  The error 403 indicates you are forbidden from making the connection to the API.  Probably due to "opted out".  You are making a secure connection to the API using https (probably TLS).  TLS uses TCP to establish a secure connection using the proxy server.  You are failing to go secure.  Can you connect using Chrome with your current URL to API.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The only way I knew to include an authorization scope was when authorizing the credentials, which requires Oauth 2.0, which I was not planning on using. Do you know of a way to include scope without requiring the end user to log in to google drive through a browser? (aka credentials.json file)

Comment: @jdweng I am sort of confused by your answer. This is supposed to be a simple application that is downloaded by the client. The application finds and downloads a game file using the API key for my google drive and installs it for the client.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I guess that makes sense. I just have no idea how to implement oauth along with an API key. The way google explained it made it seem like using an api key was an alternative to Oauth. They state so here https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158857

Comment: I am not requesting data from a user. It is strictly a one way connection to a public file. There shouldn't be any reason for someone to need to authenticate themselves. It is simply an application that retrieves a public google file that is on my drive, and downloads it using an API key.

Comment: Why can't you create direct links and then just download the file?

Comment: I remember reading that the API key was the "authentication" step when accessing my public drive. The API key represents my application when connecting to drive services. I have it configured online that the API key, when used in a request, allows for all file access on my drive. I don't see what I am missing here.

Comment: I think the direct links might just be the answer here. I think I am overcomplicating things

Comment: An http connection has many options and many ways of failing.  Google Drive API is making an http connection and the default settings are not working with your machine and need some changes.